# Pole and orders, and evaluating residue

Tags: complex-analysis

let 
$$f(z)={e^z\over z\sin 2z},$$
show that 0 is a pole.
I dont know how to show shat $0$ is a pole and i which order it have?

Comment: Do we have $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z}\sin(2z)$ or  $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z\sin(2z)}$ ?

Comment: f(z)=(e^z)/zsin(2z) the second one

Answer (score 0):

First way: estimating that the denominator has at $\;z=0\;$ a zero once because of $\;z\;$ itself and twice because of $\;\sin 2z\;$ , and the numerator never vanishes so you can try an educated guess:

$$\lim_{z\to0}z^2f(z)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^2e^z}{z\sin 2z}=\frac12\lim_{z\to0}\frac{2z}{\sin2z}e^z=\frac12\cdot1\cdot1=\frac12$$

and $\;z=0\;$ is a double pole by definition.

Second way: first, distinguish or "see" the obvious pole at $\;z=0\;$ , and now do some Laurent series in, say $\;0<|z|<0.1\;$, using the well known Taylor (Maclaurin) series of known functions:

$$\frac{e^z}{z\sin2z}=\frac{1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots}{z\left(2z-\frac{8z^3}6+\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots}{2z^2\left(1-\frac{2z^2}3+\ldots\right)}=\frac1{2z^2}\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\right)\left(1+\frac{2z^2}3+\frac{4z^4}9+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac1{2z^2}\left(1+z+\frac76z^2+\ldots\right)=\frac1{2z^2}+\frac1{2z}+\ldots$$

That's all we need: the first summand above gives you the pole's order: $\;2=\;$ the highest power of $\;z^{-1}\;$ in the Laurent series, and the other summand gives you the residue: $\;\frac12=\;$ the coefficient of $\;z^{-1}\;$ in the series

Answer (score 0):

$Hint$: $f(z)=\frac{1}{g(z)}$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z=a$ if $g(z)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z=a$.